# Is this some kind of theorem or rule of solving these types of determinants? If yes, what is it's name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I just got to know that you can write a determinant made up of with any 9 variables in the following format,
\begin{vmatrix}
a+m & b+n & c+o \\
p+a & q+b & r+c \\
p+m & q+n & r+o \\
\end{vmatrix}
as
\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
p & q & r \\
m & n & o \\
\end{vmatrix}
&
+
&
\begin{vmatrix}
m & n & o \\
a & b & c \\
p & q & r \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{array}
I've checked that both give the same values. So is there any name or statement for this rule/theorem/property?

Comment: The two determinants in the second formula are equal, since it is just an even permutation of the rows. So it can be seen as just the fact that $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ has determinant $2.$

Comment: That is, of course, just a special case of the identity matrix, when $a=q=o=1$ and the other values are $0.$